# xml Coding in Openerp

Tags: xml, odoo

i have a doubt in openerp xml coding. Does the following function works for onetomany field in openerp6.0.

```
attrs="{'invisible':[('x_form_type','==','service_bill')]}"
```

I have added the piece of code in account_invoice_view.xml but not working.when i searched i found someone reported that this wont work for onetomany in openerp 5.0

Comment: could you provide the whole XML element please ?

Comment: no it is working just a slight chnage in the code i wrote       attrs="{'invisible':[('x_form_type','=','service_bill')]}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This should Work for o2m field.
Provided that , "x_form_type" field must be there on the defined view.
If you Don't want to display that field , then make it invisible="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely the function works for onetomany fields also.